# how to select multiple files by clicking on INPUT (multiple) more than once? im losing previous files

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

So i have this part of code

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="file[]" multiple accept="image/*" />
```

and a bunch of jQuery/Ajax code to handle previews.

I managed to do "append" on previews so if user clicks on input more than once, the preview shows all previously selected files as well as the current ones.

The problem is when I click on input more than once, the array of file[] gets empty and previous files are gone. 
How to add them to the formData without losing previous selections?

Comment: the multiple attribute doesn't work like this.   It allows you to hold the ctrl/cmd key in the popup to give it a list of files all at once.   It doesn't support what you are trying to do.

Comment: You would need to use the HTML5 File API (Drag & Drop) to process one file at a time.

Comment: I believe that it is a security feature of the browser to not allow you to store the path to a file for submission later on.

You could use your JQuery to duplicate the form field possibly once one file is selected.  So select a file, add another file input field.  Repeat as needed?

Comment: @briansol, I know, I select multiple files once and then I want to select more files to the list. 
So you say it's not possible. I think about adding <input> to every chosen file, but how to transfer multiple file selected to <input> field as a value?

I mean it would work like:
1. click on multiple file selector
2. select files, click OK in popup
3. generate new <input> for every selected file and save file as field's value. But that's the clue. How to transfer selected files to input form? Is it only path to the file or what?